# Ubuntu asks for Pro unable to update

Tags: apt, updates, xubuntu

After having 3 packages held back for a little over a month I was finally able to update. After this happened I ran a new update in Software Updater and Ubuntu gave me this message:
[image]

Does this mean that I can no longer update without going Pro. Is Ubuntu forcing me to update to Pro just so I can run a standard update that I do all the time. Does anyone have similar problem like this?

Using Xubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: There is no change to existing policy, packages in *main* still get security patches, where as packages in *universe* (community sourced) do not. Ubuntu Pro provides an *optional* set of security patches for *universe*, which is what you're now being offered.  You can *enable* Pro and take advantage of it, or just ignore it (*with no change, except for ESM/Pro messages; though these can be disabled too*)   If you explore those packages, you'll quickly discover they're all *universe* packages.

Comment: I don't wan't to go Pro I will ignore this, but how am I suppose to update if this thing keeps poping up all the time just via terminal or what?

Comment: This message about *additional optional security* will **not** impact your updates, it's just a *reminder* that your system has extra security patches available if you wish. Almost everyone can access a number of *Ubuntu Pro* accounts without cost; but the message is intended to be *informational* only (*though some find the marketing nature of it annoying too*)

Comment: Then I will just stick to the command line for updates from now on. The Software updater was only usefull when you had to upgrade to new firmware and kernel and it gives you a message for restart while the command line doesn't. Hope they remove that annoying message tnx for the Info